# Is page re-render slower than component re-render?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have two design options:

two page option:

```
function PageOne() {
  return ( <> <Link to="pageTwo"><button></Link>
  <navbar>
  <contentOne>
  </>)
}
function PageTwo() {
  return ( <> <Link to="pageOne"><button></Link>
  <navbar>
  <contentTwo>
  </>)
}
```

one page option:

```
function Page()
  return ( <> <button>
  <navbar>
  button ? <contentOne> : <contentTwo>
  </>)
)
```

Would the one page option be faster since it only ever re-renders the  elements, while the 2 page option re-renders all elements even though only the content ever changes?

Comment: shouldn't really matter I would have thought, React's virtual DOM and diff-checking means that in both cases only the `contentOne/contentTwo` part would be actually touched in the real DOM. So any actual performance difference would probably depend on how the relevant functions are called and what costs those have - but the difference, if any, is likely to be miniscule in most practical cases. As ever: if in doubt, benchmark!

Comment: I prefer option 2 because yeah, it prevent unneccessary recalculations (even if it's really really small) and contains less code. I would suggest making a Component called Layout that takes children and puts out the navbar and stuff.

Comment: This is not only a question of performance but also of code quality. The first example is not DRY. It's basically duplicated code with just a single part of it being different which makes it harder to maintain. If you have a unique layout where only a certain part is always different the common stuff should be extracted into a component.